# Tag widget in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, tags, widget

I'm looking for a widget for GWT (or SmartGWT) which can be used for tags, exactly the same way as the Stackoverflow tag system when you ask a question: tags appearing like buttons with a cross to delete them. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of these two tag related GWT third party libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comp-tagging/
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-tagcloud/

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for such a widget. But both proposed libraries didn't meet my requirements, so i wrote my own library and published it on [GitHub](https://github.com/cbopp/gwt-taglist/wiki).

The library is inspired by [gwt-comp-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comp-tagging/)'s generic tag handling and gmail's label layout. No suggestion functionality has yet been implemented.